# Finding correlation per date

Tags: r, date

So I have this data that I'm working with in R which includes dates and some other numerical values.

For example:

```
Original data:                      Correlation:    

Date    A           B               Date      A-B correlation
1/1/14  0.646900002 0.826334113     1/1/14    0.115318653
1/1/14  0.749110046 0.76096474      2/1/14   -0.103099409
1/1/14  0.113140299 0.021753678         
1/1/14  0.606452255 0.686107567         
1/1/14  0.444319359 0.525262532         
1/1/14  0.606781624 0.044356839         
1/1/14  0.614123471 0.297375217         
1/1/14  0.188359271 0.241516935         
1/1/14  0.183521135 0.689139895         
1/1/14  0.589526858 0.254644093         
1/1/14  0.71034734  0.09013472          
1/1/14  0.837135625 0.201209164         
2/1/14  0.94648478  0.84068584          
2/1/14  0.626264662 0.081342849         
2/1/14  0.892623221 0.782297906         
2/1/14  0.450972567 0.47742116          
2/1/14  0.169566342 0.559258882         
2/1/14  0.784438364 0.679334501         
2/1/14  0.343981789 0.573520179         
2/1/14  0.319638902 0.32651945          
2/1/14  0.696791383 0.714156398         
2/1/14  0.945426519 0.279906366         
2/1/14  0.021251623 0.862969217         
2/1/14  0.730957108 0.778038087         
2/1/14  0.536041003 0.833652026         
2/1/14  0.957302868 0.447567636         
2/1/14  0.863476904 0.018996642         
2/1/14  0.372006386 0.313388118
```

I did this on excel using the CORREL command.

My first question is: How can I replicate this process on a bigger file (which includes millions of rows). Is there a way so that R can automatically calculate the average correlation between two columns with the same date?

My second question is: Once I've found the correlation for each date, how can I plot this as a time-series graph?

I'd prefer the simplest way possible please, since I'm a beginner :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can do something like that:

```
 df %>% group_by(date) %>%
        summarise(Correlation = cor(apples, oranges)) %>%
        mutate(MeC = mean(Correlation))
Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

        date Correlation        MeC
1 2002-01-02 -0.09607689 0.02941009
2 2002-01-03  0.15489708 0.02941009
```

Another solution might be:

```
df %>% group_by(date) %>%
    mutate(Cor = cor(apples, oranges)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(MeanCor = mean(Cor))
```

but be aware that the latter will provide a **different** result for the mean of correlations because it will average **all** correlations and then different lengths will interfere. Both measures might be useful, it depends on your purposes.

or a base R solution combining `split` and `sapply` (but maybe there is a better way):

```
sapply(split(df, df$date), function(x) cor(x["oranges"], x["apples"]))
 2002-01-02  2002-01-03 
-0.09607689  0.15489708
```

Comment: How can I plot this data into a time-series graph?

Comment: @Kevin it is not clear to me how do you want to plot and which variables. Maybe you should open a new question for that, but first of all do a research because I bet there are tons of question about plotting and last but not least maybe a reading of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might be very useful.

Comment: I try inputting:
df <- group_by(date)

but I get this error:
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @Kevin I did not write `<-` I wrote `%>%`